# How to unite two Regexp's in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby

What's the alternative to something like

```
str = "[string] somethind else"
str[/\[\w+\]/][/\w+/]
```

Whenever I want just "string" and not "[string]".

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are asking "how to unite two `Regexp`s in Ruby", but what does "unite" mean? It is not a well-known term in the Ruby community, nor is it a well-known term in the theory of regular expressions or `Regexp`s. There exists the term "union", which is well-defined for regular expressions and `Regexp`s, is that what you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
str[/\[(\w+)\]/, 1]
```

See [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ZxguYL).

With the `/\[(\w+)\]/` regex, you find the first match of `[`, followed with 1+ word chars that are captured into Group 1, and then a `]`, and `1` argument makes the output to be just the value of the first capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "[string] something else"

str[/(?<=\[)\w+(?=\])/]
  #=> "string"
```

`(?<=\[)` (`(?=\])`), a *positive lookbehind* (*positive lookahead*) requires that the match be immediately preceeded (followed) by on open (closed) bracket, but the bracket is not part of the match returned.